# Put a complete tag in an input value

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to put some tag into a input value. Here's my code:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Test</title>
    </head>
    <script src="jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function(){
            var n_cours = $("span").size();
            console.log(n_cours);
            for(var v=0;v<n_cours;v++){
                var ok = $("span:eq("+v+")")[0];
                var ok2 = $("span:eq("+v+")").text();
                var html = "<tr><td><input value='"+ ok +"'></td><td><input value='"+ok2+"'></td></tr>";
                $("table").append($(html));
            }
        });
    </script>
    <body>
        <div>
            <span>1stackoverflow</span>
            <span>2stackoverflow</span>
            <span>3stackoverflow</span>
        </div>
        <table border="1Px"></table>
    </body>
</html>
```

The output I want is this:

```
----------------------------------------------------------
| <span>1stackoverflow</span>    | 1stackoverflow        |
----------------------------------------------------------
| <span>2stackoverflow</span>    | 2stackoverflow        |
----------------------------------------------------------
| <span>3stackoverflow</span>    | 3stackoverflow        |
----------------------------------------------------------
```

But I get a different result instead:

```
----------------------------------------------------------
| [object HTMLSpanElement]    | 1stackoverflow        |
----------------------------------------------------------
| [object HTMLSpanElement]    | 2stackoverflow        |
----------------------------------------------------------
| [object HTMLSpanElement]    | 3stackoverflow        |
----------------------------------------------------------
```

How can I make it show the HTML representation?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the `outerHTML` property:

```
for(var v=0;v<n_cours;v++){
    var ok = $("span:eq("+v+")")[0].outerHTML;
    var ok2 = $("span:eq("+v+")").text();
    var html = "<tr><td><input value='"+ ok +"'></td><td><input value='"+ok2+"'></td></tr>";
    $("table").append($(html));
 }
```